A generalization of Borel-Cantelli's lemma
Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space and let $I_n = \bigcap_{k = 1}^{n}E_k$ so that $\{I_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a decreasing sequence of events ($I_{n+1} \subseteq I_{n}$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$). Suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(I_n) = 0$. In my specific case my aim is to prove that the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} P(I_n)$ is divergent.. Standard version of Borel-Cantelli's lemma doesn't tell much in this case, so I would like to understand how it is possible to prove this fact given the nature of the events $I_n$ (or equivalentelly the nature of $E_k$).
Are there some theorems which could help me in solving this problem? Is there a "standard strategy" in proving similar questions? Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Is there a typo? $E_k=\emptyset$ is a counter-example to what you have stated.

It is, I meant that this was not true in general. But given the nature of $E_k$ it is possibile that the given series diverges and I would like to understand when it's the case. Maybe I should state it in a more clear way.

Let $p_n=\mathbb{P}(I_n)$. You know that $p_n\downarrow 0$ which a priori does not imply $\sum_n p_n=\infty$ or $<\infty$; think of the case when $p_n=1/n^a$ where $a>0$....
